# Can I use loop in this code?

Tags: javascript, loops

Is it possible to use a loop somewhere in this code? It is one of the requirements and I have no idea where to use it;/ if there is anything "ugly" about the code feel free to tell me:)

```js
function check() {
    var question1 = document.quiz.question1.value;
    var question2 = document.quiz.question2.value;
    var question3 = document.quiz.question3.value;
    var question4 = document.quiz.question4.value;
    var question5 = document.quiz.question5.value;
    var question6 = document.quiz.question6.value;
    var question7 = document.quiz.question7.value;
    var question8 = document.quiz.question8.value;
    var messages = ["You passed!", "You failed"];
    var range;
    var correct = 0;
    var pictures = ["images/passed.gif", "images/failed.gif"];
    if (question1 > 5.5) {
        correct++;
    }
    if (question2 > 5.5) {
        correct++;
    }
    if (question3 > 5.5) {
        correct++;
    }
    if (question4 > 5.5) {
        correct++;
    }
    if (question5 > 5.5) {
        correct++;
    }
    if (question6 > 5.5) {
        correct++;
    }
    if (question7 > 5.5) {
        correct++;
    }
    if (question8 > 5.5) {
        correct++;
    }
    if (correct > 5) {
        range = 0;
    }
    if (correct < 5) {
        range = 1;
    }
    document.getElementById("after_submit").style.visibility = "visible";
    document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = messages[range];
    document.getElementById("picture").src = pictures[range];
}
```

Comment: depends how you define things in the markup. If you define it in a particular way, yes, you can iterate over it all.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in this way.

```
function check() {
    var answers = [
        document.quiz.question1.value, 
        document.quiz.question2.value, 
        document.quiz.question3.value, 
        document.quiz.question4.value, 
        document.quiz.question5.value, 
        document.quiz.question6.value, 
        document.quiz.question7.value, 
        document.quiz.question8.value
    ];
    var messages = ["You passed!", "You failed"];
    var range;
    var correct = 0;
    var pictures = ["images/passed.gif", "images/failed.gif"];
    for (var i = 0; i < answers.length; ++i) {
        if (answers[i] > 5.5)
            correct++;
    }
    document.getElementById("after_submit").style.visibility = "visible";
    document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = messages[range];
    document.getElementById("picture").src = pictures[range];
}
```

You can even do this ([TankorSmash](https://stackoverflow.com/users/541208/tankorsmash)'s advice)

```
function check() {
    var answers = [];
    for (var i = 1; i <= 8; ++i) {
       answers.push(document.quiz["question" + i].value);
    }
    var messages = ["You passed!", "You failed"];
    var range;
    var correct = 0;
    var pictures = ["images/passed.gif", "images/failed.gif"];
    for (var i = 0; i < answers.length; ++i) {
        if (answers[i] > 5.5)
            correct++;
    }
    document.getElementById("after_submit").style.visibility = "visible";
    document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = messages[range];
    document.getElementById("picture").src = pictures[range];
}
```

Comment: beat me to it :p @TankorSmash was thinking that too. You would have to use ```eval()``` though, which could cause a performance impact.

Comment: Oh yes, blind to find that

Comment: @TankorSmash you are completely right, sleeping with my eyes open here xP

Comment: @aahung you can remove the part about the second solution not being good practice since I was wrong. Of course having 2 loops can still be slower than 1 loop + some hard coded statements but that is nitpicking at this point.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative loop building upon the solution by ***mplungjan*** and ***aahung***.

This one uses a for-each loop on the array to make it even more clean and finishing off with a ternary operator instead of the if statement.

```
var answers = [
    document.quiz.question1.value, 
    document.quiz.question2.value, 
    document.quiz.question3.value, 
    document.quiz.question4.value, 
    document.quiz.question5.value, 
    document.quiz.question6.value, 
    document.quiz.question7.value, 
    document.quiz.question8.value
]
// Can also loop the question values as mentioned in the previous answer
/*
var answers = [];
for (var i = 1; i <= 8; ++i) {
   answers.push(document.quiz["question" + i].value);
}
*/
var messages = ["You passed!", "You failed"];
var range;
var correct = 0;
var pictures = ["images/passed.gif", "images/failed.gif"];

answers.forEach(function (value){
    (value > 5.5) ? correct++ : null;
});

document.getElementById("after_submit").style.visibility = "visible";
document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = messages[range];
document.getElementById("picture").src = pictures[range];
```

Comment: Why loop answers and not loop question values?

Comment: It is obvious that looping the questions as was mentioned in the previous answer could also be used in this answer. I will edit my answer to clarify this. @mplungjan